# Montgomery Ladder vs Double-and-Add

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, algorithm-design, side-channel-attack

I would like to know what (if any) are the advantages of using Montgomery Power ladder over the Double-and-Add-Always algorithm.
I think that firstly, Monty would be slightly faster than DoubleAndAdd. But I'm not too sure about side-channel security.

I'm asking this in the context of RSA's modular exponentiation and ECC's Elliptic Curve Scalar Multiplication.

Comment: I can add the algorithms if anyone needs them, just leave a comment. Thanks!

Comment: It will be hard to beat this article with excellent information: Marc Joye and 
Sung-Ming Yen, [_The Montgomery Powering Ladder_](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-36400-5_22) (in proceedings of CHES 2002; [alternate link](http://cr.yp.to/bib/2003/joye-ladder.pdf)).

Comment: On montgomery curves montgomery ladders enable cheap addition via differential addition in x/z form. In most other situations I'd rather create a lookup table with 32 or so entries and then double 5 times followed by one lookup and one addition.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: the point of these algorithms is that they try to resist cache-based side channel attacks; that's hard to do with a look-up based algorithm.  Yes, if you don't care about those side channel attacks (either you know no one else is sharing your cache, or you're doing ECDSA signature verify), there are considerably more efficient alternative available.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, montgomery ladders work on any kind of curves

Comment: @David天宇Wong But montgomery curves have nice properties which allow fast constant time implementations of montgomery ladders.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, those two algorithms are surprisingly close; I'll write both of them up to show how close they are.

They both can be written as a combination of three substeps:

```
A := Add( B, C )
```

This takes the two points B and C, and adds them together (I'll be writing things in additive notation; in RSA, with would be a modular multiplication)

```
A := Double( B )
```

This takes the point B, and adds it to itself (or, in RSA, a modular squaring)

```
If (cond) swap( A, B )
```

This tests a condition on the multiplier (exponent in RSA), and depending on that, either exchanges A and B, or leaves them alone.  Note that if it leaves them alone, it still performs the read and write operations; however when it writes A, it writes A's original value (and not B's value); this allows this operation not to leak any information via the cache.

Note that all these three can be done in constant time, and with constant memory accesses; hence we don't leak any information, even against an attacker who can listen to cache accesses.

Now, both algorithms use temp variables A and B, and I'll call the original point G.  The core of the DoubleAndAdd algorithm can be written as:

```
A := Double(A)
B := Add(A, G)
if (bit_i_of_multiplier_is_set) Swap(A, B)
```

(Actually, the swap operation here can be simplified; we don't care if it actually updates B)

The core of the Montgomery Ladder can be written as:

```
if (bit_i_xor_bit_i_1_is set) Swap(A, B)
A := Add(A, B)
B := Double(B)
```

There are also differences with how the two algorithms initialize A and B (Montgomery stirs in G by how it initializes A and B), and where they find the final result -- those are relatively minor.

So, given that both algorithms solve the problem of doing a point multiplication in constant time without leaking any information via the cache, how do they compare?

Well, for one, if you look at the Montgomery Ladder, the two operations it does can be done in parallel.  I would be skeptical if it would be a win to give them to two different cores (core synchronization is not cheap); however if you could have them done on a 2-way SIMD (if the add and double operations are sufficiently similar), that may be a win.

On the other hand, if you look at the DoubleAndAdd algorithm, we always add the point G.  Now, with Elliptic Curves and RSA, this doesn't buy us anything, but with Diffie-Hellman, we can pick G to make this operation cheap (say, G=2); that would speed up the first phase of the operation.  Also, in my humble opinion, DoubleAndAdd is a bit less complex than the Montgomery Ladder.

So, bottom line: there isn't actually that big of a difference; there might be some minor implementation differences.

Comment: The presence of answers of this nature is why I love SE!

Comment: I think you are talking about Double and Add Always

Comment: @David天宇Wong: well, yes, I am.  BlackAdder specifically asked about it in his question.

Comment: Oh right sorry, it wasn't mentioned in the title :o) what do you think about montgomery ladder being really constant-time? It seems like the additions and multiplications underneath aren't

Comment: @David天宇Wong: sure, the addition and doubling steps can be made constant time.  If you use the textbook definitions, they aren't; however there are other ways of implementing them that are (and are reasonably cheap).

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Comment: @David天宇Wong I don't get your point. The cost of multiplication is data independent for most CPUs. So as long as you implement your code without secret dependent array lookups and secret dependent branches, you should trivially end up with a side channel resistant implementation.

Comment: but the data you get in one round of montgomery ladder is dependent on the secret of the previous round

Comment: @David天宇Wong: "the data you get is dependent on the secret" -- that's fine, as long as what you do with the data is independent of what the data actually is.

Comment: I mean the Add(A,B) will be on different A and B depending on the bit of the secret key of last round

Comment: @David天宇Wong: they'll be on the same variables.  Now, the values that the variables are will differ (of course); we assume that our point addition routine (or modular multiply) doesn't leak any information about the data values.

Comment: Any pointers on how implementing addition and multiplication to not leak any information (through timing)? I guess if they are not constant-time (or another trick) then montgomery  ladder is based on something already vulnerable